# Upload Two images to WebServer

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, file-upload, afnetworking

Im trying to upload two images to my web server. Heres what i do now, to upload one image :

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSend);
// setting up the URL to post to
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.myweb.com.br/_resources/testeDir.php";

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
 now lets create the body of the post
 */
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

//Create the connection with the string URL and kick it off
NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[urlConnection start];
```

With one image its works fine, but, how i can send two images at the same time?

One option is to use AFNetworking, but i cant get it to work so far, heres what i tried :

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *requestHTTP = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"userfile" fileName:@"ipodfile.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:requestHTTP];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    //CGFloat progress = ((CGFloat)totalBytesWritten) / totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 100;


}];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Upload succes");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Upload failed");
}];
[operation start];
```

Heres my php code :

```
<?php
    $currentDirectory = getcwd(); 
    $uploaddir = $currentDirectory."/4/HD/";
    $uploaddir2 = $currentDirectory."/4/thumb/";
    $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
    $file2 = basename($_FILES['userfile2']['name2']);
    $uploadfile2 = $uploaddir2 . $file2;

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo $uploaddir."{$file}";
      } 

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile2']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile2)) {
        echo $uploaddir2."{$file2}";
      } 
?>
```

Comment: why not just add another image in the same request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another image to the request with a different name.

```
 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n",boundary]  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];//MOD HERE
    //and add

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile2\"; filename=\"ipodfile2.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Don't close the body until you've added both files *--%--\r\n*

[EDIT]this is how i do it:

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        //NSLog(@"image present:%d",[data length]);

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"file1\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        //[body appendData:[self encryptThisData:data]];
        [body appendData:data];
        [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:videoPath])
    {
        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:videoPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:content];
        ////NSLog(@"cur url is:%@",pathURL);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pathURL];
        //NSLog(@"data len is:%d",[data length]);

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"file3\"; filename=\"video.mov\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:data];
        [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
// close form   
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set request body 
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Comment: The line `[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n",boundary]  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];//MOD HERE ` shuold be  `[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@",boundary]  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];//MOD HERE `doesnt it? @GabCas